# Caratheodory's Theorem: finite measure implies unique and finite extension

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I'm using this version of Caratheodory's Theorem:

> If $(Ω,R,μ)$
> is a pre-measure space, the there is $μ′$
> that extends $μ$
> to $σ(R)$
> such that $(Ω,σ(R),μ′)$
> is a measure space.

I have already proven that if $μ$ is $σ$-finite, then $μ'$ is too and it's unique.

On the other hand in class it was mentioned that if $μ$ is finite (just finite) then $μ'$ is finite too, and unique.

I understand that $μ'$ is finite because $μ'(Ω)=μ(Ω)<\infty$ where Ω is in $σ(R)$ because it's a $σ$-algebra over $Ω$.

However I'm stuck with the uniqueness part, I've already taken another $v$ that extends $μ$ but I'm completely clueless as to how to prove $μ=v$.

Any help, hints, etc?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $\mu$ is finite, then it's $\sigma$-finite, so has a unique extension $\mu'$; you've already proved $\mu'$ is finite.